# Dynamically add a view in a custom layout after know layout's size

Tags: android, layout, view

I want to dynamically add a view in a custom layout (extends `RelativeLayout`). But the subview must be placed with specific coordinate and size. So I initialize and use `addView` into the method `onMeasure` (same problem with `onLayout`) of my custom layout, like this I can know the size of the layout.
But sometimes (after changing device’s orientation for example) the method `onMeasure` (or `onLayout`) are called multiple times (often twice). So the subviews are added many times.

Does `onMeasure` is the right place to dynamically add subviews ?

Comment: In this case (using `RelativeLayout`) you can use constraints for your view and then you don't need layout size!
explain your use of layout height and width to gain more specific answers!

Comment: [This](http://oi57.tinypic.com/63u6ar.jpg) is a good example of my custom layout. The events of the schedule are the subviews in my case.

Comment: in this case, you can use LinearLayout and set weightSum to your layout. for example there are 7 days in a week so weightSum should be 7 and every child's weight is 1. 
and the same for hours.

Comment: With LinearLayout, how can I place a event which starts at 11:34 and ends at 18:03 (for example) ?